# Receiving location information without having my app open in the background

Tags: android, ios

I have no knowledge in android development nor in ios apps.

Is there a way to get the user's location without my app (android/ios) being open in the background (with the user's acceptance)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can have an Android Service that listens for location changes. See [LocationManager in service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345002/locationmanager-in-service) as one example. Depending one what you are doing, the question is how should you start your service.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not going into it now. I just need to know if it's possible (IOS as well)